# MPI C++ Gather two dimensional arrays

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I have an MPI program that uses a coordinator (rank 0) and participant (all other ranks).

I'm allocating the arrays in the way that the advice says in order to have them contiguous.

```
int **alloc2DArray(int rows, int cols) {
    int *data = (int *) malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int));
    int **array = (int **) malloc(rows * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[cols * i]);
return array;
```

}

My coordinator has already scattered the requisite data and I've verified that its correct. Each participant does its calculations and ends up with a fully populated int** that needs to be gathered by the coordinator.

The number of columns will always be eight, so for a world size of four the coordinator has its part of the calculations from the scatter - an int** with dimensions two by eight.

```
int **myRows = alloc2DArray(rows, dimensions);
```

It also then contains an int** with dimensions eight * eight that I need to populate via a gather.

```
int **finalResult = alloc2DArray(dimensions, dimensions);
```

Each participant (four in this case) has its results in a similar int** that need to be gathered and combined with the coordinators results.

I've tried MPI_Gather, MPI_Gatherv and using MPI_Datatype. I'm sure the answer lies with one of them but my final array always ends up full of garbage.

In the coordinator I'm trying to gather like so - I've tried every combination of &, no &, no indices on final result, only the first index on final result (&(finalResult[0]))

```
MPI_Gather(&myRows, 0, MPI_INT, &(finalResult[0][0]), 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

In the participant I'm calling

```
MPI_Gather(myResult, 1, MPI_INT, NULL, 0, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Again whether I put &myResult or myResult doesn't seem to affect matters.

I should note that the arrays are dynamically loaded from a file so I can't hard code, and that also before the gather the int** are initialised and contain exactly what I expect them to. I am guaranteed however that the number of processes will evenly divide the dimension number, so I'm not sure if ScatterV or GatherV are appropriate.

Comment: I neglected to point out that I can't use any libraries, so boost is out.

Comment: *I neglected to point out that I can't use any libraries, so boost is out.* -- If you were to use `boost`, what would you use?  Whatever that is, investigate how `boost` does it, and implement something similar.

Comment: Also means I can't use std::vector. @PaulMcKenzie other questions I've seen have recommended using boost arrays. The issue here is how to gather a regular int** since my arrays are in order.

Comment: I struggle to understand why this is tagged as c++

Comment: Note that you don't have a 2D array. You have an array of pointers to arrays. There are significant performance disadvantages to this approach. Consider making a 1D array and wrapping it in a class that makes it look 2D. Now you get a 1D array that's much easier to pass around with and usually much faster. [Here's a good, no libraries required  example](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op)

Comment: I ended up flattening the int** to regular int[] lists, gather seems to work fine.